# Raspberry: Every binary : command not found

Tags: raspberry-pi3

When booted, my raspberry checks if the program called *reader* is running. If it is, it does nothing, but if not, it runs it.

After a bunch of time, a few hours (between 2 and 4 hours) the raspberry is completely lost. I can't connect with SSH, the program that ran is not running anymore, etc.

I tried to run a SSH client to get the error while i'm connected to it so I can watch what's in the dmesg and so on, but here is what I get :

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ tail -f /var/log/syslog
-bash: tail: command not found
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo tail -f /var/log/syslog
-bash: /usr/bin/sudo: No such file or directory
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ls
-bash: ls: command not found
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ /bin/ls
-bash: /bin/ls: No such file or directory
pi@raspberrypi:~ $
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ cd /bin/
pi@raspberrypi:/bin $ ./ls
-bash: ./ls: No such file or directory
```

If I stop the SSH session and try to connect again :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/bin $ logout
Connection to 10.25.168.59 closed.
root@me:/home/user# ssh pi@10.25.168.59
Read from socket failed: Connection reset by peer
```

I can ping the raspberry pi and NMAP says something hilarious :

```
Nmap scan report for 10.25.168.59
Host is up (-0.087s latency).
MAC Address: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx (Raspberry Pi Foundation)
```

Then if I unplug the raspi and plug it back, I can connect back to it and here are the logs from syslog : http://sprunge.us/lSSnj7

We can see at 11:17:08 it's booting but nothing more.

And here's maybe a thing that can help : The pi has the red light constantly ON while the green one blinks following that pattern : **on** for 8s, **off** for 0.5s

---

For information, my program is written in C, it opens an USB port (it is a barcode scanner) and does nothing about shutdown or reboot the machine.

I've already checked for memory peaks, CPU peaks, zombies processes, but nothing. I use only 60 Mb of RAM on 1 Gb, CPU is used at less than 2%. 110 tasks and 0.03 load average.

Why does the raspberry freezes or reboots (without killing the SSH session) but does not completely reboot, because my *reader* is not launched again ?

Any help would be very much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe some hardware problems on the SD card ?

These "not found" look like when the system is in really bad shape after a hardware failure or a `sudo rm -rf /*`

Comment: I'm able to access /bin so it was not removed.

Comment: problem was indeed the sd card.